# Replacement for Appenzeller?

Tags: cheese, casserole

A recipe for a spinach casserole / gratin calls for topping it off with Appenzeller before putting it in the oven. I cannot find Appenzeller in the store.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appenzeller_cheese distinguishes between classic, surchoix, and extra Appenzeller, but the recipe doesn't give that much detail; it just says Appenzeller.

What cheese would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cook's Thesaurus calls Appenzeller creamy and pleasantly stinky :) As a substitute they recommend  Emmentaler, Gruyère, Raclette, or Fontina so I'd just pick one of those you really like.